# can't click on element that has multiple options

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I'm trying to click an element the following way but getting an error says:

```
Failed: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
```

The code:

```js
'use strict;'
var PresentPage = function(){
    let PresentPageTitle = element(by.xpath("//*[@id='planAndDev']/div/div/div/div/matanot/form/div[2]/h4"));
    let UserPhone = element(by.id("tel"));
    let Email = element(by.id("email"));
    var AresForPresents = element(by.xpath("//*[@id='verticalRadioGrp']/div/select")).all(by.tagName("option")).then(function(options)
    { 
      return options;
    });
     this.SelectAreaToGetPresent = function()
    { 
        AresForPresents[3].click(); 
    };
};
module.exports = new PresentPage();
```

EDIT: 
When using it inside a function it works ok.

```js
this.SelectAreaToGetPresent = function()
    { 
      element(by.xpath("//*[@id='verticalRadioGrp']/div/select")).all(by.tagName("option")).then(function(options)
    { 
       options[3].click();
    });
```

Comment: Could it be that you have a typo and were looking for `AreasForPresents[3]` (i.e. missing an `a`)?

Comment: can you post the document (html) this runs against?

Comment: @Garr Godfrey unfortunately not since it is a public organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code doesn't handle the promise.

```
var AresForPresents = element(by.xpath("//*[@id='verticalRadioGrp']/div/select")).all(by.tagName("option"));
this.SelectAreaToGetPresent = function()
{ 
    AresForPresents.then((options)=> { options[3].click(); }); 
};
```

Otherwise, you need [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

```
var AresForPresents;
this.SelectAreaToGetPresent = async ()=>
{ 
    AresForPresents = await element(by.xpath("//*[@id='verticalRadioGrp']/div/select")).all(by.tagName("option")); 
    AresForPresents[3].click();
};
```